# (MYSQL) SQL select query - maybe OUTER JOIN?

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I am struggling with some sql and could use some help. I am sure it's pretty novice stuff for a lot of people.

**Here is an example:** 
I am trying to select all the pictures that are not in an album, when the albumid is supplied.

**The tables**

**Picture table**

```
    pictureid
    picturename
```

**Album_Picture Association Table**

```
    albumpictureid
    albumid
    pictureid
```

**Album Table** - I don't think this table needs to be referenced in the SQL.

```
    albumid
    albumname
```

I am assigning pictures to an album, and want to just display the pictures that havent already been assigned.

**Extra credit:** What would be even better is if I could select all the pictures in the table and be able to know which ones are in the album already, instead of omitting them from the returned data.
Then I could still show the image and just not allow it to be assigned.

Hope that all makes sense.
Thank you for any help.

using MYSQL 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first question, this query will return you the pictures where there doesn't have an association inside of your `album_picture` association table.

```
  SELECT 
    * 
  FROM 
    pictures 
  WHERE 
    pictureid NOT IN (SELECT pictureid FROM album_picture)
```

A simple way of returning both is to add another column, performing two queries (one to give you the assigned pictures and one to give you the unassigned pictures), and getting the union of both.

```
  (SELECT pictures.*, 'n' AS `assigned` .... ) UNION (SELECT pictures.*, 'y' AS `assigned` ...)
```

Comment: Thank you David Z. I tried the first one and it worked. It won;t return any already assigned. I don't really understand your second one, but I am happy for now. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can find the pictures *not* in an album with:

```
select pictureid from Album_Picture where albumid != :albumid
```

You can mark the ones in an album with:

```
select pictureid, albumid=:albumid as in_album from Album_Picture
```

Comment: I haven't seen that syntax before. Do you have a link to some documentation on it? Looks pretty nifty.

Comment: That's just some database connectors' syntax; it's usually more explanatory than the standard ?.  PDO does this: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Comment: Steve, although I used a different answer, I think your second select statement is the one I would really like to use. My query is pretty complex (as this picture/album) was just an example. So I cannot figure out how to adapt your suggestion. Can you adapt it with something like this current sql:  (From Daivd Z) SELECT 
    * 
  FROM 
    pictures 
  WHERE 
    pictureid NOT IN (SELECT pictureid FROM album_picture)   I really need the "FROM picture" to stay entacted

Answer (score 0):

Let's approach this by trying to create a result table that shows each picture and its associated album.  Due to the left outer join the pictures without an album will have a null value for the album info.  The ORDER BY statement will put all the nulls together.

```
select p.pictureid, p.picturename, a.albumid, a.albumname
from picture p
    left outer join album_picture ap
    on p.pictureid = ap.pictureid
        left outer join album a
        on ap.albumid = a.albumid
order by a.albumid
```